# showings of a movie at different times of the day

Tags: single-word-requests

I know matinee refers to an afternoon showing of a movie.
How about morning, evening, and midnight showings? Any specific terms?

Answer (score 1):

French:

- Matin = morning
- Midi = noon
- Soiree = evening
- Nuit = night

Apparently, a matinee is a show scheduled for the morning, but actually takes place past noon.
A Soiree would be a show scheduled for the evening but stretches into the night.

Since inebriated/hung-over show masters must have confused themselves as to when morning actually ends, more sober people must have had no other choice but to use the term ***morning matinee*** to emphasize that the morning "morning show" would actually take place in the morning rather than after noon.

Therefore, to concoct your own terms, in adherence to traditions

- midee for show scheduled at noon but actually shown early evening
- nuitee for show scheduled at bedtime but actually shown at midnight. People tend to use the term *midnight matinee*, which would actually "oxymoronically" mean midnight *morning show*.

Hence you now have a complete framework:

- morning matinee
- matinee
- midee
- soiree
- nuitee

Comment: If you're borrowing French words, shouldn't you borrow actual French words that mean what you want them to? [Nuitée](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nuitée) means night shift or [bed-night](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/bed-night.html).

Comment: %age of French words creolized into English, that is tastefully done thro out the centuries to the satisfaction of the Académie Française = zero. Anyway, bedtime show as stated, OK?

Answer (score -1):

Morning show = before noon or at morning

Matinee = past noon

1st show = evening

2nd show = at night ( Which ends at midnight )

Due to the large number of screens and showings in multiplexes, nowadays the cinemas only refer to the time of a show.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This answer is good and could answer the question perfectly. However, it needs some embellishing with links and references to back it up. Could you try adding some in?